# Swift NSAttribured String CSS attribute width not work

Tags: html, ios, css, swift

I have the HTML text, which I want to convert to NSAttributedString, all works fine, but one problem, I want to display blockquote tag with a vertical line on the left side, I want this line to be 3px width, but it seems that width is ignored. How I change the width of this div?
Here is my code.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
public class func NSStringToAttributed(_ nsText: String,
                                           font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)) -> NSMutableAttributedString? {

        let stringWithFont = (NSString(string: nsText).appendingFormat("<style>body{font-family: '%@'; font-size:%fpx;}</style>",
                                                                       ".SFUIText",
                                                                       font.pointSize))

        let parsedCommentHTML = stringWithFont.replacingOccurrences(of: "<blockquote>",
                                                                    with: "<div style=\"max-width: 3px;  background: #82a43a; height: transform:translateY();\"><i style=\"color:#A9A9A9\"><blockquote>\n").replacingOccurrences(of: "</blockquote>",
                                                                                                                                          with: "</blockquote></i></div>")



        if let data = String(parsedCommentHTML).data(using: .unicode,
                                                  allowLossyConversion: false) {
            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.minimumLineHeight = 20.0
            style.headIndent = 6.0
            style.firstLineHeadIndent = 6.0
            style.alignment = .left
            let attributes = [
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style ]
            if let attrString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
                                                               options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                                               documentAttributes: nil) {
                attrString.addAttributes(attributes,
                                         range: NSString(string: attrString.string).range(of: attrString.string))
                attrString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName,
                                        value: -0.2,
                                        range: NSString(string: attrString.string).range(of: attrString.string))
                return attrString
            }
        }
```

And here is result
[image]

Comment: you have miss-spelled 3px. It should be 3px and not 3fpx

Comment: @hardikparmar good point, but not still not working

Comment: Does the string already has some CSS? Because I guess the max-width is getting overridden. Try using `max-width : !important 3px;`.

Comment: @hardikparmar all CSS that string has above, I tried your option, but still without success, width and height attributes ignored

Comment: I think attributed string don't support all CSS staffs. Alternatively, in stead of lable/textview, you can use wkwebview to load the html string.

Comment: @RazibMollick so, maybe you know another way to display quotes in string, with vertical line, where quotes may be multiple?